# Error al mostrar datos de un JSON en un listview

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de mostrar una consulta donde muestro un `JSON` de una base de datos externa, pero al ejecutar la aplicación no me muestra nada.

Esta es la parte del código en donde creo que esta el error:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");

            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(new Product(
                        productObject.getString("nombre"),
                        productObject.getString("contenido"),
                        productObject.getString("extra1")
                ));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_layout, arrayList
        );
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

y estos errores me saltan

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 
>   [{"nid":"1","id":"1","fecha":"2016-11-02","nombre":"MEJORAMIENTO DE ALUMBRADO EN JARDÍN DE EMILIANO ZAPATA.","lugar":"Emiliano Zapata","contenido":"Se comenzó con la instalación de lamparas de vapor de sodio, para el jardín de Emiliano Zapata.","extra1":"14876639.jpg"},
>   {"nid":"2","id":"2","fecha":"2016-11-02","nombre":"TERMINACIÓN DE OBRAS PANTEÓN MUNICIPAL","lugar":"La Huerta, Jal.","contenido":"En el marco de las celebraciones del Día de Muertos.","extra1":"14882280.jpg"}] 
>   of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
>
> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>
> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
>
> W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>
> W/System.err:     at mx.gob.lahuerta.listas.MainActivity$ReadJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:49)
>
> W/System.err:     at mx.gob.lahuerta.listas.MainActivity$ReadJSON.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:39)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Ejemplo del JSON que estoy recibiendo:

```
[  {"nid":"1","id":"1","fecha":"2016-11-02","nombre":"MEJORAMIENTO DE ALUMBRADO EN JARD\u00cdN DE EMILIANO ZAPATA.","lugar":"Emiliano Zapata","contenido":"Se comenz\u00f3 con la instalaci\u00f3n de lamparas de vapor de sodio, para el jard\u00edn de Emiliano Zapata. Al mismo tiempo, informo el jefe del departamento que en pr\u00f3ximos d\u00edas se comenzar\u00e1 a instalar l\u00e1mparas de alumbrado p\u00fablico en calles, as\u00ed como el pr\u00e9stamo de reflectores para la plaza de toros de la localidad para lucimiento de sus fiestas taurinas tradicionales pr\u00f3ximas a realizar.","extra1":"14876639.jpg"}
 , {"nid":"2","id":"2","fecha":"2016-11-02","nombre":"TERMINACI\u00d3N DE OBRAS PANTE\u00d3N MUNICIPAL","lugar":"La Huerta, Jal.","contenido":"En el marco de las celebraciones del D\u00eda de Muertos en que las familias visitan el Pante\u00f3n Municipal para honrar la memoria de los suyos, el H. Ayuntamiento se dio la tarea de realizar obras de mejoras y conservaci\u00f3n, as\u00ed se culmina con los trabajos de las obra del pante\u00f3n municipal donde se construy\u00f3 puerta de acceso principal en el pante\u00f3n Municipal con un costo de $ 56 mil 615.22 pesos y la obra del descanso donde se realiz\u00f3 una remodelaci\u00f3n integral del \u00e1rea con una inversi\u00f3n de $ 51 mil 569.15 pesos.","extra1":"14882280.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el stacktrace o es un error de compilación?

Comment: Hola, Ya añadi el stacktrace

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo de tu JSON que recibes?

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu response es un JSONArray, cambia

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
```

por:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);
```

[   Representa un arreglo

{   Representa un objeto

```
    for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
      String id       = jsonobject.getString("id");
      String title    = jsonobject.getString("title");
      String company  = jsonobject.getString("company");
      String category = jsonobject.getString("category");
    }
```

Fuente:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441246/org-json-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Comment: Ya me mostro los resultados, pero solo me mustra el texto... la imagen no me la muestra :(

Comment: Estoy recibiendo una imagen en el JSON en el campo "extra1":""14882280.jpg", pero esa no me la muestra

Comment: Debes concatenar el valor de "extra1" con una URL, verifica si tu URL va ser variable o puedes manejarlo como una constante dentro de tu proyecto. Para mostrar tu imagen, puedes ocupar la librería, Glide. https://github.com/bumptech/glide .Saludos

Comment: ok, si funciono... otra pregunta... Existe una forma de darle un tamaño a la imagen?... porque el el ImageView tiene un tamaño, pero la imagen no llena el espacio en su totalidad.

Comment: El ImageView tiene propiedades para escalar la imagen, a lo mejor imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX) te puede ayudar para lo que necesitas, te dejo este link como la explicación de las escalas https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imi . Saludos

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu archivo .json, es en realidad un [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html):

```
[{"nid":"1","id":"1","fecha":"2016-11-02","nombre":"MEJORAMIENTO DE ALUMBRADO EN JARD\u00cdN DE EMILIANO ZAPATA.","lugar":"Emiliano Zapata","contenido":"Se comenz\u00f3 con la instalaci\u00f3n de lamparas de vapor de sodio, para el jard\u00edn de Emiliano Zapata. Al mismo tiempo, informo el jefe del departamento que en pr\u00f3ximos d\u00edas se comenzar\u00e1 a instalar l\u00e1mparas de alumbrado p\u00fablico en calles, as\u00ed como el pr\u00e9stamo de reflectores para la plaza de toros de la localidad para lucimiento de sus fiestas taurinas tradicionales pr\u00f3ximas a realizar.","extra1":"14876639.jpg"},{"nid":"2","id":"2","fecha":"2016-11-02","nombre":"TERMINACI\u00d3N DE OBRAS PANTE\u00d3N MUNICIPAL","lugar":"La Huerta, Jal.","contenido":"En el marco de las celebraciones del D\u00eda de Muertos en que las familias visitan el Pante\u00f3n Municipal para honrar la memoria de los suyos, el H. Ayuntamiento se dio la tarea de realizar obras de mejoras y conservaci\u00f3n, as\u00ed se culmina con los trabajos de las obra del pante\u00f3n municipal donde se construy\u00f3 puerta de acceso principal en el pante\u00f3n Municipal con un costo de $ 56 mil 615.22 pesos y la obra del descanso donde se realiz\u00f3 una remodelaci\u00f3n integral del \u00e1rea con una inversi\u00f3n de $ 51 mil 569.15 pesos.","extra1":"14882280.jpg"}]
```

Revisa la respuesta y dependiendo de eso recuerda que la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> - Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
> - Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35720/95

por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
```

debes usar :

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
```

código:

```
     // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
     // JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);

        for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayList.add(new Product(
                    productObject.getString("nombre"),
                    productObject.getString("contenido"),
                    productObject.getString("extra1")
            ));
        }
```