# org.json.JSONArray no se puede convertir a JSONObject

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, android-volley

estoy trayendo datos a una lista con recycle y en un fragment, estoy trabajando con PHP, MYSQL, ANDROID y volley. Mi siguiente error es que al traer los datos no se muestran o no se listan por el siguiente error **"org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject"**. Los datos si están viniendo ya que en el log me lo muestra. Especificamente es el metodo listar lo que me trae problemas ya que alli estoy utilizando el **JSONArray y JSONObject**. En la imagen esta el log donde muestra el problema y mi codigo para que se pueda entender mejor de lo que hablo, Gracias de antemano.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.iproject.Adapter.RecyclerActividades;
import com.example.iproject.model.entidadactividades;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.iproject._conexion.URL;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String  JSON_URL = _conexion.URL_LISTAR_ACTIVIDADES+"listar_actividades.php";

    //Button bt3;
    //TextView Listaractividades;
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private List<entidadactividades> datactiviti;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //bt3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        //Listaractividades = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        datactiviti = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView =  (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);

        listar();
        return view;
    }
    private void  listar() {
        //RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        //StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        entidadactividades entity = new entidadactividades();
                        entity.setNombre(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));
                        entity.setFecha_venci(jsonObject.getString("fecha_venci"));
                        entity.setDescripcion_activi(jsonObject.getString("descripcion_activi"));
                        datactiviti.add(entity);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
                setrecycleview(datactiviti);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }

    });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void setrecycleview(List<entidadactividades> datactiviti){

        RecyclerActividades recycleradapter = new RecyclerActividades(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), datactiviti);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        LinearLayoutManager llm  = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);


    }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error al mostrar datos de un JSON en un listview](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36058/error-al-mostrar-datos-de-un-json-en-un-listview) Ese error ocurre cuando tratas un `JSONArray` como si fuese un `JSONObject`. Es simple, un `JSONArray` está encerrado entre `[]` y un `JSONObject` está encerrado entre `{}`. Tienes que analizar qué estructura tiene el JSON para saber cómo tienes que leerlo.

Comment: Tienes mucha razón amigo, muchas gracias. ya arregle mi Json y esta es la forma correcta como debe de estar `[
  {
    "nombre": "Base de datos",
    "fecha_venci": "2019-09-29",
    "descripcion_activi": "Crear la base de datos en un servidor para tener conexion remota"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Modulo Cuentas y criterios",
    "fecha_venci": "2019-09-29",
    "descripcion_activi": "Hacer un CRUD de todas las tablas que realizan el modulo cuentas y criterios"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "TEST",
    "fecha_venci": "2019-11-10",
    "descripcion_activi": "test al codigo"
  }
]` un [ ]