# Codigo para obtener xml o Json Java

Tags: java, json

Estoy intentando obtener los datos que vienen de estos *link*
http://122.6.54.26/swapi/api/data/json
http://21.26.54.26/swapi/api/data/xml

he intentado muchos métodos pero al final siempre me da error cuando pasa por esta línea  `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);`

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://15.26.54.26/swapi/api/data/xml")
                    .build();


            Response responses = null;

            try {
                responses = client.newCall(request).execute();

                json = responses.body().string();

                System.out.println("JSON: " + json);

                try {


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);


                    //   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonObj);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Carro");
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("idintelisis");
                        System.out.println("TESTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE: " + id);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException ex) {

                    System.out.println("Errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr: " + ex);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Este es el **long** del error que lanza cuando revienta esa línea

> 01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"},{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf.CarrosActivity$POST.doInBackground(CarrosActivity.java:114)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf.CarrosActivity$POST.doInBackground(CarrosActivity.java:65)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
>   01-11 10:04:47.487 6541-7024/pa.com.tropigas.pedidostf I/System.out: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"},{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":null,"carro":null,"cargapkt":"sd5"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Eh usado **Postman** para revisar el resultado del **Json** e igualmente el **Json** del **log** y todo indica que el **Json** está correcto en cuanto a estructura no entiendo por qué se rompe al intentar convertirlo a un *objeto* de *Json*

Comment: En el **JSON**  que recibes del servidor están viniendo objetos que **Java** no sabe cómo convertir. Si tienes algún tipo de dato no definido **default** en **Java** hazle un un método para convertirlo a `JSONObject`

Comment: ya provaste haciendo primero esto `{{"idintelisis":101,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":"01/02/2017","carro":"CD-95","cargapkt":"sd5"},{"idintelisis":102,"observaciones":"Nitin","fecha":"01/02/2016","carro":"CD-5","cargapkt":"2"}}`

Comment: ya que estas diciendo que vas a recibir un json object, el cual contendra otros objetos

Comment: Usa la libreria de google Gson https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 1):

**Esta sera la solucion del problema**

El objeto que estoy intentando captura es `JsonArray` no `JsonObject`

probe esto

`JsonArray arr = new JsonArray (resultado obtenido)`;
Y luego intente  obtener `JsonObject` de `arr` utilizando el método `getJSONObject(arr)`

Ejemplo:

```
JsonArray arr = new JsonArray (resultado obtenido);
    Para (int i = 0; i <arr.length (); i ++) {
    JsonObject ob = arr.getJSONObject (i);
}
```

Comment: Exactamente, tu contenido es [{"....."}] en realidad es un JSON
Array no un JSONObject, ve lo que se comenta en esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35720/95

Comment: @Elenasys te puedo agregar a skype para una consulta?

Comment: que tal, si claro!

Comment: @Elenasys cual es tu skype jaja

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que estás enviando un arreglo de objetos en la api, cuando debes mandar un solo objeto, solo debes meter el arreglo original en "{}" es decir tu api debe devolver lo siguiente :

```
{ arreglo : [{"idintelisis":101,"obser..." ... (resto de contenido del JSON) ] }
```

Comment: Ya probe como dices agregando los "{}" no aun sigue dando error