# JsonObject Android

Tags: android, json, object, servidor

Estoy elaborando un `listview` a través de un json que traigo desde un servidor. El detalle es que no puedo pasar mis datos a un `listview` en esta función trato de guardarlos para de ahi moverlos al `listview`

```
public ArrayList<String> ObtDatosJSON(String response) {
    ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

        String texto;
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            texto= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre")+ " " +
                       jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Direccion") + " " +
                       jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Telefono") + " " ;
            listado.add(texto);
            Log.d("Arreglo de texto",texto);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Este es un ejemplo de mi JSON:

```
{
    "Datos": [
        {
            "Nombre": "Fitzgerald, Travis, Prescott, Declan",
            "Direccion": "6088 Tincidunt, Ave",
            "Telefono": "0500 772161"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Emmanuel, Buckminster, Karly, Dexter",
            "Direccion": "1711 Luctus Rd.",
            "Telefono": "(016977) 4322"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Cecilia, Wynter, Madonna, Kasimir",
            "Direccion": "756-1905 Semper St.",
            "Telefono": "0800 1111"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Kelly, Quail, Nasim, Alea",
            "Direccion": "1449 Risus, Av.",
            "Telefono": "0800 518475"
        },
    ]
}
```

Si yo le quito `"Datos"`: mi función si los trae y los guarda pero si no lo quito no lo mete (entra el `JsonException`)

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Posible duplicado : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35655/error-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-con/35720#35720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas intentando recoger un objeto como un array, deberías recoger el objeto como JSONObject y luego de ahí sacar el array.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Datos");
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta acababa de leer la documentacion pero no ubicaba donde poner cada cosa hasta que tu me lo solucionaste

Comment: para eso estamos, si la respuesta es correcta, por favor, marcala como correcta para que se cierre la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

```
                        Type listType_ = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ProgramacionDto>>() {}.getType();
                        List<ProgramacionDto> areas = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(response.result), listType_);
                        
                        Log.d("Fecha Servidor",areas.get(0).FechaServidor);
                        Log.d("Fecha PDT",currentDateandTime.toString());
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).