# Problema al traerme JSON enANDROID org.json.JSONException: Value dejala at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, jsonobject

Tengo un problema a la hora de recoger un JSON desde mi bbdd. Necesito pasar los datos del JSON al list view y cuando lo recoge al pasarlo al objeto de la clase me da el error especificado. ¿Que puedo hacer? Adjunto imágenes a  continuación.El enlace que adjunto a continuacion es el JSON que me devuelve:[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí]

esta es la clase principal:

```
package soundfy.soundfy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    AsyncHttpClient cliente;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    obtenerDatos();
}

private void listarCanciones(String respuesta) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "ENTRÓ CON EXITO por SEGUNDA VEZ",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    ArrayList<CancionesAttr> listaCanciones = new ArrayList<CancionesAttr> 
();
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(respuesta.replaceAll("[^\\x00- 
\\x7F]", ""));
        Log.i("JSON Parser", String.valueOf(json));
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            CancionesAttr c = new CancionesAttr();
            //c.setId(json.getJSONObject(i).getString("idcanciones"));

c.setNombre_cancion(json.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_cancion"));
            Log.i("JSON NOMBRECANCION", String.valueOf(c.nombre_cancion));
            c.setAno(json.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ano"));


c.setAlbum(json.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_album_fk"));


c.setArtista(json.getJSONObject(i).getString
("nombre_artista_cancion_fk"));

        c.setGenero(json.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_genero_fk"));
        listaCanciones.add(c);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<CancionesAttr> a = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, ` 
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);`
        lv.setAdapter(a);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    private void obtenerDatos(){
        String url = 
"http://soundfyproject.000webhostapp.com/consulta.php";
        cliente.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] 
responseBody) {
                if(statusCode == 200){
                    Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
                    int duracion = Toast.LENGTH_LONG; // Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto,
                            "ENTRÓ CON EXITO",
                            duracion);
                    toast.show();
                    listarCanciones(new String(responseBody));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] 
responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
                int duracion = Toast.LENGTH_LONG; // Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto,
                        "HA FALLADO LA CONEXIÓN CON LA BBDD",
                        duracion);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

y esta la clase del objeto canciones:

```
   package soundfy.soundfy;

public class CancionesAttr{
    int id;
    String nombre_cancion;
    String album;
    String artista;
    int ano;
    String genero;

    public CancionesAttr() {
    }

    public CancionesAttr(int id,String nombre_cancion, String album, String artista, int ano, String genero) {
        this.nombre_cancion = nombre_cancion;
        this.album = album;
        this.artista = artista;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre_cancion() {
        return nombre_cancion;
    }

    public void setNombre_cancion(String nombre_cancion) {
        this.nombre_cancion = nombre_cancion;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getArtista() {
        return artista;
    }

    public void setArtista(String artista) {
        this.artista = artista;
    }

    public int getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    public void setAno(int ano) {
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  nombre_cancion + album + artista;
    }
}
```

este es el error que me devuelve:

> 10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value dejala at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at soundfy.soundfy.MainActivity.listarCanciones(MainActivity.java:41)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at soundfy.soundfy.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:17)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at soundfy.soundfy.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:67)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:351)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   10-25 19:41:25.032 9079-9079/soundfy.soundfy W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Comment: Por favor cambia las imágenes por el texto del código o de los mensajes de error. Las imágenes son difíciles de analizar, más aún desde dispositivos pequeños. Puedes pulsar en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta en ese sentido. Gracias.

Comment: No se puede visualizar el código, agregarlo como texto!

Comment: @jorgesys ya esta adjuntado bien gracias!

Comment: @javierlenza excelente Javier, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica que lo que intentas parsear no es un JSONObject, es un JSONArray, pero incluso este valor contiene saltos de linea y retorno de carro:

```
["dejala","2018", "ahora", "melendi", "pop"]\r\n\r\n
```

Recuerda que:

> JSONObject usa los contenedores `{` y `}`  JSONArray usa los
>   contenedores `[` y `]`

Podrías realizar un reemplazo de caracteres para obtener un json, pero lo ideal es definitivamente que corrijas la respuesta para que esta entregue un JSONObject:

```
{ "dejala" , "2018" , "ahora" , "melendi" , "pop"}
```

Comment: vale conseguí que devuelva un objeto JSON en vez de un array, el problema estaba en el bucle del php, pero no consigo quitar los retornos de carro y los saltos de linea, con lo cual no se me rellena el **ListView** y se me queda el activity en blanco, ¿cómo podría quitar el **retorno de carro** y los **saltos de linea** ? Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Jorgesys !

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar de Obtener una respuesta con las variables definidas.
En la consulta SQL que mantienes puedes utilizar "select canciones as "Canciones" from album." como ejemplo.

**De esta manera en vez de recibir como respuesta**

["dejala","2018","ahora","melendi","pop"].

**Puedes recibir algo como esto:**

[{"nombre_cancion":"dejala","ano":"2018","nombre_album_fk":"ahora","nombre_artista_cancion_fk":"melendi","nombre_genero_fk":"pop"}]

**Para luego declarar las variables de la siguiente manera:**
c.setNombre_cancion(json.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_cancion")).....

como lo tienes actualmente.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

EDIT: Si el error que mantienes es el que indico en mi respuesta, [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35655/error-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-con?rq=1) hay otra que lo explica de mejor manera.