# como leer un archivo Json en android

Tags: android-studio, json

este es el archivo json

```
[{"user_relacion":5,"notif":"relacion","latitud":0.490274,"longitud":-74.563262,"fecha":"2020-10-22","plac":"123qwe"},{"user_relacion":5,"notif":"acorde","latitud":2.490274,"longitud":-76.563262,"fecha":"2020-10-22","plac":"123qwe"}]
```

Así he tratado de extraer la información con la clave notif

```
  try {
       String myJsonString= "notif";
       JSONObject myJsonjObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
       String myJson = myJsonjObject.getString("text");
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+myJson, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda [siempre esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35720/95):

Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.

Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.

En este caso es un JsonArray (inicia con "[" y termina con "]" ):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes realizarlo de esta forma usando la clase [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray)`  :

```
 try {         
            JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray(myJsonString);
            //JSONObject myJsonjObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
            String myJson = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("notif");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+myJson, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Pero como son varios elementos en tu JSONArray puedes iterar sobre el array para obtener todos los valores de "notif":

```
try {

    JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray(myJsonString);
    
    //Itera elementos en JSONArray
    for(int i = 0; i<myJsonArray.length(); i++){
        String myJson = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("notif");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+myJson, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la libreria `GSON` y generar tus clases con `jsonschema2pojo`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ClaseGetSet getSet = gson.fromJson(tuJSONString, ClaseGetSet.class);
```

//Clase GetSet

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ClaseGetSet {

@SerializedName("properties")
@Expose
private Properties properties;

public Properties getProperties() {
return properties;
}

public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
this.properties = properties;
}

}
```