# Como encontrar Content dentro del Json de chatGPT usando Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

¿Como puedo encontrar "content" del json que manda chatGPT usando kotlin?.

Este es el Json que normalmente manda chatgpt

> 

```
{
 'id': 'chatcmpl-6p9XYPYSTTRi0xEviKjjilqrWU2Ve',
 'object': 'chat.completion',
 'created': 1677649420,
 'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
 'usage': {'prompt_tokens': 56, 'completion_tokens': 31, 'total_tokens': 87},
 'choices': [
   {
    'message': {
      'role': 'assistant',
      'content': 'The 2020 World Series was played in Arlington, Texas at the Globe Life Field, which was the new home stadium for the Texas Rangers.'},
    'finish_reason': 'stop',
    'index': 0
   }
  ]
}
```

Usando kotlin puedo llegar a message de esta manera

```
val jsonArray = jsObct.getJSONArray("choices")
val result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("message")
```

pero necesito lo que hay en content

> `{ 'role': 'assistant', 'content': 'The 2020 World Series was played in Arlington, Texas at the Globe Life Field, which was the new home stadium for the Texas Rangers.'}`

¿Alguien sabe que más necesito hacer para llegar a 'content'?, porque si al final de "getString" coloco un "get", puedo seguir avanzando pero solo es 1 carácter lo que muestra y no funciona.

Estuve buscando y encontré esta forma en la solución de otro post con un tema distinto.

```
for (i in 1..jsonArray.length()) {
     val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
     val id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("id").getString("videoId")
```

Pero tampoco funcionó, ¿Alguien sabe que más podría hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda [siempre esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35720/95):

> Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.
>
> Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.

Ahora, si análisis tu JSON:

```
{
 'id': 'chatcmpl-6p9XYPYSTTRi0xEviKjjilqrWU2Ve',
 'object': 'chat.completion',
 'created': 1677649420,
 'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
 'usage': {'prompt_tokens': 56, 'completion_tokens': 31, 'total_tokens': 87},
 'choices': [
   {
    'message': {
      'role': 'assistant',
      'content': 'The 2020 World Series was played in Arlington, Texas at the Globe Life Field, which was the new home stadium for the Texas Rangers.'},
    'finish_reason': 'stop',
    'index': 0
   }
  ]
}
```

para obtener "content", a partir de tu objeto, debes obtener el array 'choices', después el objeto  'message' y dentro de este objeto puedse obtener el valor de 'content'

```
//obtener el array 'choices'
val jsonArray = jsObct.getJSONArray("choices")
//obtener el objeto 'message' del primer objeto (indice 0) en el array
val messageObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("message")
//dentro del objeto 'message' obtiene el valor "content"
val valorContent = messageObj.getString("content")
```